# Is it possible to estimate the initial distribution of (hidden) state using Baum-Welch algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, numeric

I have implemented the Baum-Welch algorithm and I am playing with some toy data, generated with a known distribution. The data is normally distributed, had different mean and standard deviation depending on the hidden state. There are 2 states. The algorithm seems to converge for most of the parameters apart from the initial distribution of the hidden state, which always converges to either (0; 1) or (1; 0) depending on the random data.

Is it normal in this algorithm? If so I would appreciate some references, if not some hints how to find the bug.

Code (F#). First a helper module:

```
module MyMath

let sqr (x:float) = x*x

let inline (./) (array:float[]) (d:float) =
  Array.map (fun x -> x/d) array

let inline (.*) (array:float[]) (d:float) =
  Array.map (fun x -> x*d) array

let map f s =
  s |> Seq.map f |> Seq.toArray

let normalize v = 
  let sum = Seq.sum v
  map (fun x -> x/sum) v

let row i array = seq { for j in 0 .. (Array2D.length2 array)-1 do yield array.[i,j]}
let column j array = seq { for i in 0 .. (Array2D.length1 array)-1 do yield array.[i,j]}

let sum (v:float[]) = v |> Array.sum
let sumTo N (f:int->float) = Seq.init N f |> Seq.sum
let sum_column j (array:float[,]) = column j array |> Seq.sum
let sum_row i (array:float[,]) = row i array |> Seq.sum

let mean data = (sum data)/(float (Array.length data))
let var data = 
    let m=mean data
    let N=Array.length data
    let sum=Seq.sumBy (fun x -> sqr(x)) data
    sum/(float N)

let induction start T nextRow =
  let result =  Array.zeroCreate T
  result.[0] <- start
  for t=1 to T-1 do
    result.[t] <- nextRow t result.[t-1]
  result

let backInduction last T previousRow =
  let result =  Array.zeroCreate T
  result.[T-1] <- last
  for t=T-2 downto 0 do
    result.[t] <- previousRow t result.[t+1]
  result

let inductionNormalized start T nextRow =
  let result =  Array.zeroCreate T
  let norm = Array.zeroCreate T
  norm.[0] <- sum start
  result.[0] <- start./norm.[0]
  for t=1 to T-1 do
    result.[t] <- nextRow t result.[t-1]
    norm.[t] <- sum result.[t]
    result.[t] <- result.[t]./norm.[t]
  (result, norm)
```

The main module:

```
module BaumWelch

open System
open MyMath

let mu (theta : float[,]) q = theta.[q,0]
let sigma (theta : float[,]) q = theta.[q,1]

let likelihood getDrift getVol dt parameters state observation  =
    let mu = getDrift parameters state
    let sigma =  Math.Abs (getVol parameters state:float)
    let sqrt_dt = Math.Sqrt dt
    let residueSquared = 
        let r = Likelihood.normalizedResidue mu sigma dt sqrt_dt observation in r*r
    let result = (Math.Exp (-0.5*residueSquared))/(sigma * (Math.Sqrt (2.0*Math.PI*dt)))
    if result<0.0 then failwith "Negative density, it certainly shouldn't have happened"
    else result

let alphaBeta b (initialPi:float[]) initialA observations= //notation in comments from the Erratum for Rabiner
    let T = Array.length observations
    let N = Array2D.length1 initialA
    let alphaStart = Array.init N (fun i -> initialPi.[i] * (b i observations.[0]))  //this contains \bar{\alpha}
    let alpha_j_t (previousRow:float[]) t j  = (sumTo N (fun i -> previousRow.[i]*initialA.[i, j]))* (b j observations.[t]) //this contains \bar{\alpha}
    let alphaInductionStep t previousRow = Array.init N (alpha_j_t previousRow t)
    let (alpha, norm) = inductionNormalized alphaStart T alphaInductionStep
    let betaStart = Array.init N (fun i -> 1.0/norm.[T-1])
    let beta_j_t (nextRow:float[]) t j = (sumTo N (fun i -> initialA.[j, i]*nextRow.[i]*(b i observations.[t+1])))/norm.[t]
    let betaInductionStep t nextRow = Array.init N (beta_j_t nextRow t)
    let beta = backInduction betaStart T betaInductionStep
    (alpha, beta, norm) //c_t = 1/norm_t


let log_P_O norm = 
  let result = norm |> Seq.sumBy (fun norm_t -> Math.Log norm_t)//c_t = 1/norm_t
  if Double.IsNaN result then failwith "log likelihood is NaN"
  else result

let gamma (alpha:float[][], beta:float[][], norm:float[])  i t = 
    alpha.[t].[i]*beta.[t].[i]*norm.[t]

let xi b (initialA:float[,]) (alpha:float[][]) (beta:float[][]) (observations:float[]) i j t = 
    alpha.[t].[i]*initialA.[i,j]*(b j observations.[t+1])*beta.[t+1].[j]


let oneStep llFunction dt (initialPi, initialA, initialTheta) observations =
  let T = Array.length observations
  let N = Array2D.length1 initialA
  let b = llFunction dt initialTheta
  let (alpha, beta, norm) = alphaBeta b initialPi initialA observations
  let gamma = gamma (alpha, beta, norm)
  let xi = xi b initialA alpha beta observations
  let pi = Array.init N (fun i -> gamma i 0) //Rabiner (40a)
  let A =  //Rabiner (40b)
    let A_func i j = (sumTo (T-1) (xi i j))/(sumTo (T-1) (gamma i))
    Array2D.init N N A_func
  let mean i = (sumTo T (fun t -> (gamma i t) * observations.[t]))/(sumTo T (gamma i))//Rabiner (53)
  let var i = 
    let numerator = sumTo T (fun t -> (gamma i t) * (sqr (observations.[t]-(mean i))))
    let denumerator = sumTo T (gamma i)
    numerator/denumerator
  let mu i = ((mean i) + 0.5*(var i))/dt
  let sigma i = Math.Sqrt ((var i)/dt)
  let theta = Array2D.init N 2 (fun i k -> if k=0 then mu i else sigma i) 
  let logLikelihood = log_P_O norm //Rabiner (103)
  (logLikelihood, (pi, A, theta))

let print (ll, (pi, A, theta)) = 
  printfn "pi = %A" pi
  printfn "A = %A" A
  printfn "theta = %A" theta
  printfn "logLikelihood = %f" ll

let baumWelch likelihood dt initialParams observations =
  let tolerance = 10e-5
  let rec doStep parameters previousLL =
    //print (previousLL, parameters)
    let (logLikelihood, parameters) = oneStep likelihood dt parameters observations
    if Math.Abs(previousLL - logLikelihood) < tolerance then (logLikelihood, parameters)
    else doStep parameters logLikelihood
  doStep initialParams -10e100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to guess my way through the F#, but here are some observations:

1) How many initial states do you have observations for? If the answer is "just one" then the probability of the observations can be written as P(state 0) P(obs | state is 0) + P(state 1) P(obs | state 1). Depending on which of the two P(obs | state is X) is higher, the maximum likelihood solution will have either P(state 0) = 1 or P(state 1) = 1. I would only expect to see intermediate probabilities for the initial state when it is possible that you are observing observations that derive from a number of different initial states - for instance, if you have more than one stretch of toy data to analyse at the same time.

2) In looking for a bug, it can help to produce toy data where the answer is entirely obvious. If I had n stretches of data of the form {0, 0, 0, 0...} and m stretches of data of the form {1, 1, 1, 1...} I might hope to see state 0 assigned initial probability n/(m +n) - or of course m/(n + m), since the program doesn't know which state I wish to link with which sequence.

3) Another way to check programs is to look for some sort of consistency or conservation check. Since the model of two initial states can be made the same as a model with just one initial state, a special set of transition probabilities for the first observation, and possibly a special dummy first observation, you could check its behaviour with two initial states against its behaviour with just one initial state and some fudging.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that using only one observation sequence almost always leads to probs converging to 0/1.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for some time, I think the behaviour I described might actually be correct. The reason being that in the observed data this distribution was "used" only once, so intuitively there is not enough statistics to infer the distribution. Having said that I think the algorithm should be able to recover (with reasonable accuracy that is) the actual value of the hidden state variable at time 0 - because this had impact on the whole time series.